# Connection closed unexpectedly in WCF Service

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

Hi i have stuck with an issue of underlying connection was closed using C#.I configured my webconfig time out high only but i dont know where i made mistake. I am posting my webconfig file. please rectify my mistake. values comes from db context entity by list.

** Web Config:**

```
<basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICommonGateway" closeTimeout="00:40:00"
       openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:40:00"
       allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
       maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
       messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
       useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
           maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
             realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
```

Comment: It's quite possible (even likely) that the root cause is there is an exception being thrown in your service that is not being caught (handled), which is resulting in the service crashing.  This will tear down the service which can result in the connection being closed.  In other words, this most likely has nothing to do with the config or the timeouts, but more likely has to do with the code of the service.  Check your Event Viewer and IIS logs to see if anything shows up there, and/or enable WCF Tracing.